How to fit an image exactly inside an Excel cell using Python and XlsxWriter?
I'm working on a Python script that inserts images into Excel cells using the XlsxWriter library. My goal is to have each image fit precisely within its cell, without any overflow or unused space.
Here's a simplified version of my current approach:
import xlsxwriter
from PIL import Image
import io

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('image_in_cell.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Set column width and row height
col_width = 25  # in Excel units
row_height = 100  # in Excel units
worksheet.set_column(0, 0, col_width)
worksheet.set_row(0, row_height)

# Open and resize the image
image_path = 'sample_image.jpg'
with Image.open(image_path) as img:
    img_width, img_height = img.size
    aspect_ratio = img_width / img_height
    cell_width = col_width * 8  # Approximate conversion
    cell_height = row_height * 1.2  # Approximate conversion
    if aspect_ratio > cell_width / cell_height:
        new_width = cell_width
        new_height = int(cell_width / aspect_ratio)
    else:
        new_height = cell_height
        new_width = int(cell_height * aspect_ratio)
    img = img.resize((new_width, new_height), Image.LANCZOS)
    # Convert image to bytes
    buffer = io.BytesIO()
    img.save(buffer, format='JPEG')
    image_data = buffer.getvalue()

# Write the image to the cell
worksheet.insert_image(0, 0, image_path, {'image_data': image_data})
workbook.close()

Is there a way to get a perfect and tight fit inside the cell for an image?

Rather than scale the actual image a better approach would be to set the image scaling in XlsxWriter to scale the image to the cell. You can do that in two ways.
The first and best approach (which doesn't need any manual or programatic scaling) is to use the worksheet.embed_image() method which uses the Excel option to "Place in Cell" which is available in Excel 365 versions from 2023 onwards.
# Widen the first column to make the caption clearer.
worksheet.set_column(0, 0, 30)
worksheet.write(0, 0, "Embed images that scale to cell size")

# Embed an images in cells of different widths/heights.
worksheet.set_column(1, 1, 14)

worksheet.set_row(1, 60)
worksheet.embed_image(1, 1, "python.png")

worksheet.set_row(3, 120)
worksheet.embed_image(3, 1, "python.png")


The second approach, which will work in any version of Excel is to set the image scaling properties to match the cell size. You can do this by adding scale options to the worksheet.insert_image() method:
worksheet.insert_image("B23", "python.png", {"x_scale": 0.5, "y_scale": 0.5})

To calculate the scale you will need from the dimensions and DPI of the image, since Excel takes the image DPI into account.
The calculation would be something like this (width and height are in pixels):
x_scale = (cell_width / image_width) * (image_width_dpi / 96.0)
y_scale = (cell_height / image_height) * (image_height_dpi / 96.0)

if keep_aspect_ratio:
    if x_scale < y_scale:
        y_scale = x_scale
    else:
        x_scale = y_scale

